# Putting my name ahead of my co-authors on a latex title page

Tags: titles

Grad student here, getting ready to submit a paper.  I've done 92% of the work on a paper I'm submitting, but I've got three (senior) co-authors.  I want to put my name up top, and put their names in a row below mine.  Right now, it has the names all in a row, with the last author on the bottom:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, amstext, setspace, color, geometry, enumitem, hyperref, versions, tikz, cite, tabularx,tabulary, subfig, lscape, parskip}
\usepackage{lineno}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{.125in}
\usepackage{pslatex}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}

%\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspace
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}     %Expectation operator
\title{My excellent paper about Science}
\author{Lead Author\\Dept\\ School \and Co-Author1\\Dept\\ School \and Co-Author2\\Dept\\ School \and Co-Author3\\Dept\\ School}
\date{This version: April 9, 2013}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

How would I change this to put myself at the top?

Comment: The `titlepage` package facilitates that kind of customisation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`article` class has very limited author formatting (most journal classes redefine this) however without redefining lots of internals just make yourself wide:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, amstext, setspace, color, geometry, enumitem, hyperref, versions, tikz, cite, tabularx,tabulary, subfig, lscape, parskip}
\usepackage{lineno}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{.125in}
\usepackage{pslatex}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}

%\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspace
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}     %Expectation operator
\title{My excellent paper about Science}
\author{\makebox[.9\textwidth]{Lead Author}\\Dept\\ School \and Co-Author1\\Dept\\ School \and Co-Author2\\Dept\\ School \and Co-Author3\\Dept\\ School}
\date{This version: April 9, 2013}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```